# Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Contact Is Null

Tags: experience-analytics, pipelines, tracking

I'm currently trying to identify a contact using

```
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(user)
```

and an exception keeps being thrown

> "this.Contact should not be null".

Debugging confirms that `Tracker.Current.Session.Contact` is indeed null. All the blog posts and Sitecore documentation I've read, mention nothing about Contact possibly being null when identifying a contact. This is all being run in an `httpRequestProcessed` pipeline.

What are the possible reason to get the contact as null in current session?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure it runs before the `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.HttpRequest.EndAnalytics` processor in the `httpRequestProcessed`  pipeline.  Otherwise, the contact is set to null in the `EndAnalytics` pipeline by `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EndAnalytics.ReleaseContact` processor.